# Java Generics - cannot be applied to given type

Tags: java, generics

I have some code similar to this:

```
public class Main {

    private static abstract class Bar {}

    private static class SubBar extends Bar {}

    private static abstract class Baz<T extends Bar> {

        private T t;

        public void setT(T t) {
            this.t = t;
        }

    }

    private static class SubBaz extends Baz<SubBar> {}


    private void foo(Baz<? extends Bar> baz, Bar bar) {
        baz.setT(bar);
    }
 }
```

That results in error:

```
error: method setT in class Baz<T> cannot be applied to given types;
required: CAP#1
found: Bar
reason: actual argument Bar cannot be converted to CAP#1 by method invocation conversion
where T is a type-variable:
T extends Bar declared in class Baz
where CAP#1 is a fresh type-variable:
CAP#1 extends Bar from capture of ? extends Bar
```

I don't understand why. The method setT should accept something that extends Bar and I am passing something of class Bar.

Comment: Me not. Abstract names only confuse me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The method setT should accept something that extends Bar and I am passing something of class Bar.

That's exactly the problem: `<? extends Bar>` means "Some unknown type that is `Bar` or a subclass of it". Since you don't know which type it is, it's actually impossible to call `setT()` in that context, except with a `null` parameter.

This will work as expected:

```
private void foo(Baz<Bar> baz, Bar bar) {
    baz.setT(bar);
}
```

There are, I am sure, hundreds of variations of this questions on Stackoverflow. It seems almost every programmer at first misunderstands what the `?` wildcard is for and uses it wrongly.

Its utility is in the situation where your `Bar` class has a `public T getT()` method. A variable of type `Baz<? extends Bar>` could hold objects of both `Baz<Bar>` and `Baz<SubBar>`, and you could call `getT()` on it to get something that is a `Bar` (or some subclass) and can be used like that.

Comment: Perhaps it would be better to write `Baz<? super Bar>`, since `baz` acts as a consumer.

Comment: @axtavt that might or might not be what is intended.

Comment: @axtavt I think the best option is `<T extends Bar> void foo(Baz<? super T> baz, T bar)`. You correctly identified that it is acting as a consumer, but the extra type parameter is more flexible if you extend the `Sub` classes again. For example, this allows you to pass in a `SubBaz` and a `SubSubBar`.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is not type safe. If you had:

```
private static class OtherSubBar extends Bar {}
```

You could then do:

```
Baz<SubBar> baz = new Baz<SubBar>();
foo(baz, new OtherSubBar());
```